# 2016 Task Scheduler Only Runs the first action in the list

Tags: windows, server, scheduled-tasks

I have a simple Task Schedule job that runs a program 6 times, sending to it  a different Argument each time.

This has been working well for some years, but on 2016 Server it only runs the first action and then it stops.

Any ideas of a fix? I have looked on google for all fixes etc, but they haven't worked and seem to be for 2017 and back

Answer (score 0):

Based on my past experience, this behavior could caused by one of the following:

1. If your task targets a batch file of an executable file, try to check Windows Task Manager for that file running under "Processes" tab. Select each of your target batch/exe then End Process button. This may have caused by a seemed-to-stuck process but still on "Running" status.
2. On Task Scheduler, check for your task's "Last Run Result". This could be having code other than 0x0 (which is the successful run). If so, check for details under "History" tab below this pane.

Comment: To clarify everything was running as scheduled. Then I rebooted to install updates. After that not one of the jobs has restarted. They are all using the same Admin login that I RDP in as

Comment: try to check your on task's properties. Action tab > Edit > check on "Program/Script". You can put in the executable filename (with extension) under "Program/Script" and the folder path in "Start in (optional)". Some executable files won't run if full path having like "C:\PROGRA~1\...\...\.exe" is placed on Program/Script, it should work to separate the exe and the path.